# Class not Found error in Module

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I have 3 modules in my application: Patients, Songs, PatientSongs

I want Songs url to display all songs. I want Patients url to display all patients.

For PatientSongs I would like to show the result of a join in the songs table.

My Module in PatientSongs is configured ad below:

```
return array(
        'factories' => array(
            'Songs\Model\SongsTable' =>  function($sm) {
                $tableGateway = $sm->get('SongsTableGateway');
                $table = new SongsTable($tableGateway);
                return $table;
            },
            'SongsTableGateway' => function ($sm) {
                $dbAdapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
                $resultSetPrototype = new \Zend\Db\ResultSet\ResultSet();
                $resultSetPrototype->setArrayObjectPrototype(new \Songs\Model\Entity\Song());
                return new TableGateway('songs', $dbAdapter, null, $resultSetPrototype);
            },

        ),
    );
```

Im getting an error that reads `Fatal error: Class 'Songs\Model\Entity\Song' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\zf2-tutorial\module\PatientSongs\Module.php on line 41`.

My module structure for Songs is `Songs\src\Songs\Model\SongsTable` and `Songs\src\Songs\Model\Entity\Song`

I cant figure out why it cant find this path.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Are you including all the correct files? That somtimes messes up the usage of classes in namespaces.

Comment: Are you using some sort of ORM? If yes please tag your post better.